# How to check if HTTP request is external

Tags: c#, .net, http, request

I'm writing a HTTP module in .NET (C#) for all our web applications. This is an error handler that catches all unhandled errors and displays our company error page. However, my boss wants me to display one error page for internal users and another error page for external users. Some of our applications are used by our suppliers outside our domain.

I have everything set up working properly, except I don't know the code to check if the request is internal or external. What is the C# code for this? I imagine it's an if statement.

Thanks!

Comment: `if (target_of(addresss) != 'internal') { show_external_error(); }` in basic pseudo-code...

Comment: In practice, it's not really possible to do this in a secure/watertight way.

Comment: Is everyone who uses the application authenticated? If so, you could associate your internal users with an "Internal user" role and then branch based on that.

Comment: What do you consider internal and external?  Same subnet, IP range, etc?

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

And check if the IP Address/Host is within your network and display the appropriate page.